# Passport number mismatch on US visa

Tags: visas, usa, passports, colombia

A Columbian national is coming to the United States for a visit.

She has noticed that her passport number and the passport number listed on her visa are different. Is this normal, or a potential problem?

Comment: Is the passport number of an older passport or an unknown passport? Also, for how long is planning to visit?

Comment: The question about the mis-matched visa numbers and the question about the minumum funds ought to be separate questions.

Comment: both visa and passport are new

Comment: $1,600 USD will go quickly in a city like San Francisco, but will get you a long way in a city like Memphis. It depends on where your friend is going and for how long.

Comment: I have edited out your second question (about money).  You could ask it as a new question, but please clarify whether you are asking about requirements to enter the country, or about how much it costs to stay in the US (which would need more information about her plans).  The length of the visit is also relevant.

Answer (score 4):

If the passport number, and the passport number listed on the visa, do not match then this mismatch could cause serious difficulties during travel. For example, a border control officer could conclude that she was somehow trying to use somebody else's visa to enter the country.

She should contact the US agency which issued her visa, tell them about the problem she noticed, and ask them what they can do to correct the situation. This should obviously be done as soon as possible *before* commencing travel.

Comment: Agreed.  I had a similar problem with a US Visa a few years ago (incorrect date in the Annotation) and they fixed it and issued a new visa foil within about 15 minutes.